# Can Firebase Storage rules be changed dynamically for authenticated users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I'm using **Firebase Storage** to store educational videos which can be accessible only to paid subscribers of a particular video (via a web app).

By default, I don't allow read and write permissions to any of the videos (even if the user has been authenticated using Firebase authentication) but **want to allow the read permission to a video if it has been purchased by the authenticated user**.

Can it be done ? If not, is there any alternate way of achieving the same ?

Comment: This is not easy at the moment. See this [post on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/77i9CRlwg88/iQsE78CbGQAJ) for a great explanation of one approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Just have some other associated flags with the user accounts.

You have a master list of videos or links, and each user a list of accessible videos  (which would be the ID of that video). If the ID of the video is in the user list then they cannot watch it.

When a user subscribes etc, just add the ID's to that list.